# Does Google hand over captcha IPs to webmasters?

Tags: tor, google, ip, captcha

Google gets to know a user's IP when someone enters a captcha even if they are using tor (see http://www.wired.com/2014/12/google-one-click-recaptcha/). So, If I go to a non-google website, such as cnn.com, and it asks me for a captcha for submitting a particular form, will it hand over my IP to cnn?

**NOTE:I have only used CNN as an example and this question is NOT about cnn.com**

Comment: What is your evidence that Google gets Tor users' real IP addresses? The article you linked to says nothing about Tor, it just makes a vague statement that Google is using the IP address as part of its bot detection algorithms. That statement _does not mean_ that Google has some way to get the real IP address of a user who is behind Tor, a proxy or a VPN.

Comment: If you are visiting CNN.com, then CNN.com already knows your IP address. Why does the captcha matter at all? Also as @MikeScott has already said, nobody is saying that google's captcha can bypass Tor. If it could, that would be a huge vulnerability in Tor that people would scramble to fix.

Comment: Chances are that if Tor's NoScript add-on didn't block the CAPTCHA, it doesn't pose too much of a risk of finding your real IP.

Comment: @user54791 CNN.com shouldn't be able to get your IP. As long as you're using Tor, they'll just have the IP of your exit node. And certain Java/Flash applets on websites (usually blocked by NoScript) can get your IP even if you're using Tor.

Comment: @KnightOfNi Sorry, that's what I meant - both CNN and Google will only know the IP of the Tor exit node. But the point is that CNN already has it before the user even submits the captcha, so there is no need for them to ask Google.

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually answer your question, no, Google does not provide the IP address of the user back to the original website. According to the [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify), Google will supply the website with a JSON object basically containing either true or false.

```
{
  "success": true|false,
  "error-codes": [...]   // optional
}
```

But none of this really even matters, because recaptcha does not have any special powers that allow it to get a user's real IP address when behind Tor. Even if it did supply the user's IP address, it would only know the IP address of the Tor exit node, which CNN already has from you visiting the page.